# How to create a Google Drive-like directory?

Tags: javascript, html, css, http, google-drive-api

I am working on a project which requires form input and utilizes that input to add documents to a document directory. On the other hand, we want the input sent through the form to be sent through a server as an HTTP request to some back-end code such as python, Java, or C++. The application would execute and return outputs of the data associated with the input. Some sample images are provided below.

[image]

(The plus opens up a modal box with an associated input form.)

Additionally, we want to add functionality so that the right side-bar displays the statistics of the most recent clicked on the document (provided by the back-end code sent through the server). I think that I will have to use some sort of database such as mySQL, but how does that fit with the application-side programming (python/Java/C++)? Overall, we are having major issues implementing this. Any recommendations as to how to implement this as well as concepts relating to how Google Drive (a similar mechanism and framework) operates would be of help. If there any questions, I am happy to respond!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Easiest answer: hire a developer